# How to pull deleted, archived, suspended users data to Google sheets from Admin SDK >> Reports API using Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api

How to import deleted, archived, suspended USERS data (user email, deleted date, org unit path, archive date, suspended date) to Google sheets from Admin SDK >> Reports API using Appscript. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please be mindful to **always include any research/sample scripts you've done on your end** when posting questions as much as possible. Please see the guidelines about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as this is an integral part in this community.*

**RECOMMENDATION:**

You can use this sample script below as reference. This script is based to a sample from [Google Apps Script Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/quickstart/apps-script#step_1_create_the_script)

```
function listUsers() {
  
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    var values = [];
    var userKey = 'all';
    var applicationName = 'admin';
    var optionalArgs = {
      maxResults: 100
    };

    var response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, optionalArgs);
    var activities = response.items;
    if (activities && activities.length > 0) {
      Logger.log('REPORTS:');
      for (i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
        var activity = activities[i];

        //ONLY GET DATA IF ACTION IS EITHER "SUSPEND_USER", "DELETE_USER", or "ARCHIVE_USER"
        if(activity.events[0].name == "SUSPEND_USER" || activity.events[0].name == "DELETE_USER" || activity.events[0].name == "ARCHIVE_USER"){
            Logger.log('%s: %s (%s)', activity.id.time, activity.events[0].parameters[0].value,
            activity.events[0].name);
            //RETRIEVES THE TIMESTAMP, USER'S EMAIL, & THE EVENT NAME THAT WAS PERFORMED TO THE USER
            values = [[activity.id.time, activity.events[0].parameters[0].value,activity.events[0].name]]; 

            //SET THE DATA TO SHEET
            var lrow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
            sheet.getRange("A"+lrow+":C"+lrow).setValues(values); 
        }

      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No reports found.');
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

Before you run the script, you need to add the `AdminReports` API on your Apps Script editor:

**1. Click `Services` plus icon**

[image]

**2. Choose `Admin SDK API`**

[image]

**3. Click `version` drop-down, select `reports_v1` and `Add`**

[image]

**SAMPLE SHEET**

[image]

**RESULT**

*After running the sample script, the **timestamp** when the action was made, **user email address** and the **action** made (Suspended/Deleted/Archived) will be added to the sheet:*

[image]

***Here's the Execution logs result for reference:***

[image]

Comment: Wow awesome, it almost works. Only problem is, it is listing only today's events.

Comment: If I remove the max result argument then I'm getting around 35 results which is only for last 2 days.

Comment: Since this issue is now specific than to what was posted about "How to pull deleted, archived, suspended users data to Google sheets from Admin SDK", please post a new question specific for the issue.

Comment: Done, have posted a new question, link below for your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67654227/having-issues-with-the-appscript-pulling-data-from-google-workspace-using-report