# Having issues with the Appscript pulling data from Google workspace using Reports API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-workspace, google-directory-api

The following code is pulling data to Google sheets from Google workspace using Reports API. However it is giving me only last 2 days of data not sure why,  there are no limits set in the script.

The code is the reference of the following question:

[How to pull deleted, archived, suspended users data to Google sheets from Admin SDK >> Reports API using Appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604789/how-to-pull-deleted-archived-suspended-users-data-to-google-sheets-from-admin/67608829?noredirect=1#comment119563597_67608829)

function listUsers() {

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var values = [];
var userKey = 'all';
var applicationName = 'admin';
var optionalArgs = {
  maxResults: 100
};

var response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, optionalArgs);
var activities = response.items;
if (activities && activities.length > 0) {
  Logger.log('REPORTS:');
  for (i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
    var activity = activities[i];

    //ONLY GET DATA IF ACTION IS EITHER "SUSPEND_USER", "DELETE_USER", or "ARCHIVE_USER"
    if(activity.events[0].name == "SUSPEND_USER" || activity.events[0].name == "DELETE_USER" || activity.events[0].name == "ARCHIVE_USER"){
        Logger.log('%s: %s (%s)', activity.id.time, activity.events[0].parameters[0].value,
        activity.events[0].name);
        //RETRIEVES THE TIMESTAMP, USER'S EMAIL, & THE EVENT NAME THAT WAS PERFORMED TO THE USER
        values = [[activity.id.time, activity.events[0].parameters[0].value,activity.events[0].name]]; 

        //SET THE DATA TO SHEET
        var lrow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
        sheet.getRange("A"+lrow+":C"+lrow).setValues(values); 
    }

  }
} else {
  Logger.log('No reports found.');
}
```

}

Comment: I'm guessing that you need to make it a page request and use pageToken to go through all of the available pages.

Comment: You have any idea how to try that?

Comment: Here's a simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55307907/7215091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your code contains a limit for the maximal value of results per page:

```
var optionalArgs = {
  maxResults: 100
};
```

Set this value to `1000` instead of `100` or remove it - the default value for `maxResults` is `1000` - as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list)

Should you want to retrieve more than 1000 results, you will need to retrieve `nextPageToken` from the response and pass it as `pageToken` to the `optionalArgs` for the next request.

You can reapet the request in a loop until you obtain all results.

Code modification:

```js
function listUsers() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    var userKey = 'all';
    var applicationName = 'admin';
    var optionalArgs = {
        maxResults: 1000
    };

    var response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, optionalArgs);
    var activities = response.items;
    if (activities && activities.length > 0) {
        Logger.log('REPORTS:');
        for (i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
            var activity = activities[i];

            //ONLY GET DATA IF ACTION IS EITHER "SUSPEND_USER", "DELETE_USER", or "ARCHIVE_USER"
            if (activity.events[0].name == "SUSPEND_USER" || activity.events[0].name == "DELETE_USER" || activity.events[0].name == "ARCHIVE_USER") {
                Logger.log('%s: %s (%s)', activity.id.time, activity.events[0].parameters[0].value,
                    activity.events[0].name);
                //RETRIEVES THE TIMESTAMP, USER'S EMAIL, & THE EVENT NAME THAT WAS PERFORMED TO THE USER
                values = [
                    [activity.id.time, activity.events[0].parameters[0].value, activity.events[0].name]
                ];

                //SET THE DATA TO SHEET
                var lrow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
                sheet.getRange("A" + lrow + ":C" + lrow).setValues(values);
            }

        }
    } else {
        Logger.log('No reports found.');
    }


    //////// ADD THE FOLLOWING TO YOUR EXISTING CODE:


    while (response.nextPageToken) {
        var optionalArgs = {
            maxResults: 1000,
            pageToken: response.nextPageToken
        }
        var response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, optionalArgs);
        var activities = response.items;
        if (activities && activities.length > 0) {
            Logger.log('REPORTS:');
            for (i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
                var activity = activities[i];

                //ONLY GET DATA IF ACTION IS EITHER "SUSPEND_USER", "DELETE_USER", or "ARCHIVE_USER"
                if (activity.events[0].name == "SUSPEND_USER" || activity.events[0].name == "DELETE_USER" || activity.events[0].name == "ARCHIVE_USER") {
                    Logger.log('%s: %s (%s)', activity.id.time, activity.events[0].parameters[0].value,
                        activity.events[0].name);
                    //RETRIEVES THE TIMESTAMP, USER'S EMAIL, & THE EVENT NAME THAT WAS PERFORMED TO THE USER
                    values = [
                        [activity.id.time, activity.events[0].parameters[0].value, activity.events[0].name]
                    ];

                    //SET THE DATA TO SHEET
                    var lrow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
                    sheet.getRange("A" + lrow + ":C" + lrow).setValues(values);
                }

            }
        } else {
            Logger.log('No reports found.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, it works fine now. 1 last thing, this code is giving me event date, user email, event name. Is it possible that I can pull more information about these user in the same code like user name, user creation date, etc?

Comment: Not directly, but once you obtain the user email, you can call the method `activities.list` again - now with the `eventName` `CREATE_USER` and setting `filters` to `USER_EMAIL==XXX`  - whereby `XXX` is the email of the deleted user. See [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list) and [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/admin-user-settings#CREATE_USER) documentation for correct implementation.

Comment: How to FILTER the data by date? Say i want data only for last 10 days, I tried this but not working: if (activity.events[0].name == "DELETE_USER" && 
            Utilities.formatDate(new Date(activity.id.time), "GMT+1", "mm/dd/yyyy") > Utilities.formatDate(new Date('05/20/2021'), "GMT+1", "dd/mm/yyyy"))